# Edit mode is deletes the wrong cell after I resort table order

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I have a tableview that lists about 10 cells in order from oldest to newest.  When I turn on "editing mode" and delete cells, everything appears to work properly.

But I have created some functions that resort these cells into different orders based on various properties.  When I use editing mode in these different sort orders, the wrong cells appear to get deleted.

Here is the code for one of my sort functions.

```
func sortPokemonListbyAveIV(){
        self.pokemonList.sortUsingComparator{
            (obj1: AnyObject, obj2: AnyObject) -> NSComparisonResult in
            let first = obj1 as! NSDictionary
            let second = obj2 as! NSDictionary
            var firstIVRange = ""
            var secondIVRange = ""
            if((first["iv"] as! String).containsString("Sorry")){
                firstIVRange = "IV: 1 - 2%"
            } else {
                firstIVRange = (first["iv"] as! String).stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString("--", withString: "-")
            }
            if((second["iv"] as! String).containsString("Sorry")){
                secondIVRange = "IV: 1 - 2%"
            } else {
                secondIVRange = (second["iv"] as! String).stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString("--", withString: "-")
            }
            // let firstIVRange = first["iv"] as! String
            // let secondIVRange = second["iv"] as! String
            let firstAveIV = self.avgIV(firstIVRange)
          //  print(firstIVRange)
            let secondAveIV = self.avgIV(secondIVRange)
            let result = firstAveIV - secondAveIV
            return (result < 0) ? .OrderedDescending
                : (result == 0) ? .OrderedSame : .OrderedAscending
        }
    }
```

And here is the code for my delete function.

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, commitEditingStyle editingStyle: UITableViewCellEditingStyle, forRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
    if editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyle.Delete {
        let data = self.pokemonList[indexPath.row]
        self.pokemonList.removeObject(data)

        self.images.removeObjectForKey(data["imageId"] as! String)
        let idToRemove = self.ids[indexPath.row]

        let appDel:AppDelegate = UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as! AppDelegate
        let context:NSManagedObjectContext = appDel.managedObjectContext
        if( objects[data["imageId"] as! String] != nil)
        {
            context.deleteObject(objects[data["imageId"] as! String]!)

        }
        do {
            try context.save()
        } catch _ {
        }

        self.ids.removeObject(idToRemove)
        let ref = FIRDatabase.database().reference()
        let userId = FIRAuth.auth()!.currentUser!.uid
        let key = ref.child("users")
        let b = key.child("\(userId)")
        let c = b.child("scan")
        let d = c.child(idToRemove as! String)
        d.removeValue();

        tableView.deleteRowsAtIndexPaths([indexPath], withRowAnimation: UITableViewRowAnimation.Automatic)
        tableView.reloadData()
    }
}
```

I suspect I need to edit the delete function code to take into account the current sort order active in the tableview.  I'm not quite sure how to do this though.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to call `tableView.reloadData()` after `tableView.deleteRowsAtIndexPaths`. Since calling `reloadData` will trigger whole bunch of tableView delegate and datasource method, like `cellForRowAtIndexPath`, `numberOfRowsInSection`, etc.